# What does the closure notation `x => {}` mean?

Tags: scala

```
.map(line => {
//transformation and actions
})
```

In Scala, I'll see that transformation, and within some lines that do other actions or transformations. My questions are: What is that transformation called, what is the end state after that transformation, and are there other ways to write it?

Comment: It is really not clear what you are asking. Can you give a more concrete example of the problem or ask a more specific question?

Comment: It is better to edit the question rather than providing more information in the comments. As author you are allowed to change the question :)

Answer (score 4):

`map` is a high order function that expects another function as parameter. It's widely used, you have it in common structures like `Option`, `Seq`, `List` etc.
Looking at the signature, you can try to understand what it does:

```scala
map[B](f: A => B)
```

Imagine a `List[A]`, `map` method expects a function that transforms `A` into `B` and it will convert all the elements in the list to `B` type.

To be more specific, imagine a list of integers `List[Int]`, you could pass a function that transform an Int into String `Int => String` and you will get a `List[String]` as result.

As `B` is "open", you can pass almost anything to the `map` method

Also, you can pass a defined function to `map`, you can pass an anonymous function (just the code itself) and you can do it with `()` if the code is only one line, or using `{}` as your example if you write multiple lines.

In the case of `.map(line => {})` you can add almost anything you want inside the `{}`, probably you will use `line` inside.

For example:

```scala
.map(line => {
 val a = "my line has "
 a + line.length.toString + " characters"
})
```

In the case of `List` it will convert it into another `List[String]`

Another example returning more than one value, as @francoisr comment

```scala
.map(line => {
   val l = line.lenght
   (l, line) //what we return
}
```

And it will return you a `List[(Int, String)]`

Comment: @Stef You'd have to return that value on the final line of the `{}` block, along with your other value so the output type would be `List[(String,String)]`

Answer (score 3):

@Javier has provided a correct answer, so I'm just going to expand on the syntax front, because I believe this is where your confusion originates.

The braces have nothing to do with `map` itself, they are only there to denote that the body of the closure (the function you are passing to `map`) consists of more than a single line, so we put them in a *block*.

The concept of *expression block* arises everywhere in Scala. Any time an expression is expected, it is valid to use a block rather than a single line, and the value of the block will be the value of the last expression inside that block.

The exact same thing happens when we define a method

```
def times2(a: Int): Int = { 
    // Do something complex here
    a * 2
}
```

If the method definition is a single line, you can remove the braces:

```
def times2(a: Int): Int = a * 2
```

The same goes with the body of closures, or for any expression in the language.

If you had a list of `Ints` and wanted to double their values, you could write it in any of the following ways (and even more are valid):

```
val list = List(1,2,3,4)
list.map(a => a * 2)
list.map(a => { a * 2 })
list.map(a => times2(a))
list.map(times2)
list.map(times2(_))
list.map(_ * 2)
```

Another example that has nothing to do with closures or methods:

```
val a = {
   // Do something complex here
   42
}
```

Whenever the initialization code for `a` is not trivial enough to fit on a single line, we put in inside a block. Again, the value of a block expression is the value of the last expression of the block, in this case `42`.